# PHP - counting values in array for each row recursively from DB

Tags: php, mysql, recursion, nested-loops

What i'm trying to do is printing the number of values on a certain code in my SQL. For example i wanna know how many rows have the `code` 123456 in a DB. Basically i have to do it recursively with the `code` changing each time and print once the code and the quantity of rows associated.

After this i have to print the sum of all the values on a certain code (recursively for each code as well).

Here's the not working code

```
$query_voucher1 = "SELECT * FROM voucher WHERE consegnato= 0 ORDER BY codice";
$risultato_query_voucher1 = @mysql_query($query_voucher1);
$prevcodice = NULL;
$curcodice = 10;
while ($row_voucher1 = mysql_fetch_row($risultato_query_voucher1)) {
  if ($curcodice != $prevcodice){
    $temp_query_value = mysql_query("SELECT valorelordo FROM voucher WHERE codice='$row_voucher1[2]' AND consegnato=0");
    $array_temp_query_value = mysql_fetch_row($temp_query_value);
    echo "<tr>
            <td>" . $row_voucher1[2] . "</td>
            <td>" . count($array_temp_query_value) . "</td>
            <td>" . $prevcodice . "</td>
            </tr>";
            $prevcodice = $row_voucher1[2];
                }
             $curcodice = $row_voucher1[2];
            }
```

I thought i could use the same query, first counting the values and than summing the values for printing it. The summing part is not done yet tho.

Comment: `mysql_*` functions are deprecated since 5.5.0 and removed from 7.0.0 & higher, please use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` instead.

Comment: Btw you could do it in a single query : `SELECT valorelordo, count(id) as theCount FROM voucher WHERE consegnato=0 GROUP BY codice ORDER BY codice ASC`

Comment: @Bob0t Does this should solve the problem? How would be the working code?

Comment: do request, then `echo '<pre>'; print_r($the_result);` rebuild with it.